# Full screen apps keep switching places

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I'm getting a really annoying side effect happening in osx that I can't seem to find a way to fix: for some reason the full screen applications keep switching positions. For example, if I have Safari, Mail and Xcode open in full screen, in exactly that order, every once in a while they will swap positions (eg. Xcode will sometimes move to the left, so the that swiping left will bring me to Safari instead of mail). The order of these applications is important for productivity purposes, and it gets really confusing when you have 6 of them open and all of a sudden Mail goes from spot 6 to spot 2.

Any ideas how to get this switching of places to stop?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because and should be migrated to apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question!

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Go to System Preferences > Mission Control and make sure that "Automatically rearrange spaces based on recent use" is **not** ticked.

Answer (score 0):

On Macos Sonoma it's:
System Settings -> Desctop & Dock -> Mission Control section (At the botttom)
And same checkbox "Automatically rearrange spaces based on recent use".